Delphi 10.3 Firemonkey Android application - how to print to POS thermal printer over USB-C port?
I use Delphi 10.3 to make a Firemonkey Android application. I need to print on a POS thermal printer. If the printer is connected via Bluetooth then everything works fine. However, I don't know how to access the printer with a USB-C port.
Here is the code I use for Bluetooth:
Adapter := TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter;
remoteDevice := Adapter.getRemoteDevice(StringToJString(targetMACAddress));
sock := remoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UID);
ostream := sock.getOutputStream;

...

// Reset Printer
ostream.write(StringToJA(chr(27) + chr(64),'iso8859-2') );
// Slovenia/Croatia
//ostream.write(StringToJA(chr(27) +  chr(82) + chr(14),'iso8859-2') );
//ostream.write(StringToJA(chr(27) +  chr(29) + chr(116) + chr(33),'iso8859-2') );
// PC852 (Latin2)
// ostream.write(StringToJA(chr(27) +  chr(116) + chr(36),'iso8859-2') );
//podaci o firmi
ostream.write(StringToJA(escBoldOn,'iso8859-2') );
 
ostream.write(StringToJA(escNewLine +escNewLine+escNewLine +escNewLine, 'iso8859-2'));

Sleep(250);
ostream.flush();
ostream.close;


USB is a bunch of protocols and you would have to identify what your particular USB POS printer supports. If serial see: Communicating with serial USB device over Android

Use a usb serial port library for Android from Winsoft

for the Winsoft component, I know, I wonder if there is another way.

You can do what Winsoft did - and learn how to program USB in Android for yourself.
